# Creating a User using Duo Security Admin API

Tags: javascript, coldfusion, two-factor-authentication

I am following this documentation for the Duo Security Admin Api: https://duo.com/docs/adminapi

I am trying to create/delete a user using their API in my ColdFusion webapp but the documentation only indicates that a post command needs to be used. No examples are given and I’m not sure where to start. I’m Assuming they mean to post like when submitting a form? But I’m unsure.

I am trying to create a user and also delete a user using the following code. Neither works as I am not seeing the user being created or deleted in my admin console. And the browser console is not showing any information either.

Create a User:

```
<!--- Create the user in the DuoSecurity Admin API --->
<cfhttp method="post" url="https://api-2fa0b2f8.duosecurity.com/admin/v1/users?username=#get_user.userid#&realname=#get_user.displayName#&email=#get_user.email#" />
```

Delete a User

```
<!--- Deleted the user in the DuoSecurity Admin API --->
<cfhttp method="delete" url="https://api-2fa0b2f8.duosecurity.com/admin/v1/users/#get_user.userid#" />
```

If I paste my cfhttp url in a browser I see this result:

```
{"code": 40401, "message": "Resource not found", "stat": "FAIL"}
```

Do I need to somehow also send over my application key and secret somehow?

Can anyone point me in the right direction? Thank you.

Comment: Never used the API, but .. yeah, they're saying submit the required information (username, email, etc...) via POST, rather than GET. The POST could be a done via a `<form method="post">`, `<cfhttp>` call, ajax post, etc...

Comment: Yes, it's an HTTP POST you need to send to them. Try using CFHTTP and update this question with some attempted code if you need more help. They have links to demo client code in their API docs. Take a look at the Java example to get an idea of how to craft your CF code.

Comment: Thanks. I just edited my question with my code snippet.

Comment: probably a bit too late, but the same was happening to me because I needed to request admin api access to support (auth api ≠ admin api)

Answer (score 1):

**application key and secret**  probably need to be sent via `<cfhttpparam>`

You are looking for something like

```
  <cfhttp method="delete" url="https://api-2fa0b2f8.duosecurity.com/admin/v1/users/#get_user.userid#" />
    <cfhttpparam type = "header" name = "appkey" value = "#appkey#">
    <cfhttpparam type = "header" name = "secret" value = "#secret#">
  </cfhttp>
```

Or the `<cfscript>` equivalent.

Comment: I've added those parameters but still have the same result. No errors are thrown but my user isn't deleted or created in the Duo Security admin console. The documentation mentions that response codes are given, https://duo.com/docs/adminapi#create-user. Is there anyway to log them in the browser console or onscreen? That might provide some insight.

Comment: Postman (https://www.getpostman.com/) it's a great tool to make API requests and see what's coming back.

Comment: @AlexBaban That tool is really cool! Using that tool I see the following error:
 {
    "code": 40101,
    "message": "Missing request credentials",
    "stat": "FAIL"
}
Found that error explanation in their documentation: 40101 Missing request credentials
EXPLANATION: The Authorization header was missing or formatted incorrectly.
RESOLUTION: Ensure that the Authorization header exists and is formatted correctly.

Comment: There is an "Authentication" section in this page (https://duo.com/docs/adminapi#api-details) which explains how to authenticate.

Comment: This is tricky, never dealt with HMAC before. Found an online HMAC generator that i think is working. I now recieve a timestamp error: {
    "code": 40105,
    "message": "Bad request timestamp",
    "stat": "FAIL"
}
I am submitting the date as a header in the following format: Wed, 25 Jul 2018 12:54:18 -0000

Comment: [Update] How are you calculating the timestamp? It doesn't look it's the current time in UTC.  You can get that error when the time sent is too far ahead/behind the server time. *"The request date/time was more than five minutes before or after Duo's current server-side time."* https://help.duo.com/s/article/1338?language=en_US

Comment: @BrianFleishman Did you integrate the HMAC generator with Postman?