# Creating a user using the Duo Security Admin API

Tags: java, two-factor-authentication, google-duo

Following the documentation for the [Duo Security Admin API](https://duo.com/docs/adminapi), I am trying to create/delete a user. The documentation only indicates that a post command needs to be used. No examples are given and I’m not sure where to start.

I am trying to create a user and also delete a user using the following code. Neither works as I am not seeing the user being created or deleted in my admin console.

```json
{"code": 40101, "message": "Missing request credentials", "stat": "FAIL"}
```

When I paste my URL I get this error and user is not created. What am I doing wrong?

```java
import java.io.*;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;

public class duo {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        // Create a neat value object to hold the URL
        URL url;
        url = new URL("https://api-e9770554.duosecurity.com/admin/v1/users");

        // Open a connection(?) on the URL(??) and cast the response(???)
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        // Now it's "open", we can set the request method, headers etc.
        connection.setRequestProperty("accept", "application/json");

        // This line makes the request
        InputStream responseStream = connection.getInputStream();
    }
}
```

Comment: Related: [Creating a User using Duo Security Admin API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51508629/creating-a-user-using-duo-security-admin-api)

Comment: I checked that question but I am still not able to understand it.

Comment: ?Date=Sat,14Aug202105:06:46+0000&Integration key:Secret key=DILV6EJV15MYP20WO801:DLr5bzSztvhL2Po4gSSN4E0AOIqEUaW72gYbB0r9&=api-e9770554.duosecurity.com&=/admin/v1/users&=username=xyz                              Now I am getting no response

Answer (score 0):

While calling to duo admin API you missed the authentication . The duo admin API uses HTTP Basic Authentication to authenticate requests. Use your Duo application's integration key as the HTTP Username. Generate the HTTP Password as an HMAC signature of the request. This will be different for each request and must be re-generated each time. [Duo Admin API API Detailes](https://duo.com/docs/adminapi#api-details). Refer Duo API request authentication [Duo Admin APi authentication](https://duo.com/docs/adminapi#authentication)

Below is code for generation of HMAC signature.

```
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import javax.crypto.Mac;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.util.Base64;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Hex;

@Service
@Slf4j
public class GenerateSignature {

    public String generateTheToken(List<String> urlArgs, Map<String, String> params, String ikey, String skey)  {
        String canonicalString = generatecanonicalString(urlArgs,params);
        return getAPISignature(canonicalString,ikey,skey);
    }

    public String generatecanonicalString(List<String> urlArgs, Map<String, String> params)
    {
        String canonicalString = String.join("\n", urlArgs);
        canonicalString+="\n";
        String parametersString=params.entrySet().stream().map(entry->entry.getKey()+"="+entry.getValue())
                .collect(Collectors.joining("&"));
        canonicalString+=parametersString;
        System.out.println(canonicalString);
        return canonicalString;
    }

    public String getAPISignature(String url,String ikey,String skey)  {

        Mac sha1Hmac = null;
        try {
            sha1Hmac = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA1");
            SecretKeySpec secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(skey.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8), "HmacSHA1");
            sha1Hmac.init(secretKey);
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | InvalidKeyException | IllegalArgumentException e) {
            log.error("error in");
            return StringUtils.EMPTY;
        }
        byte[] signatureBytes = sha1Hmac.doFinal(url.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        String  signature= Hex.encodeHexString(signatureBytes);
        String auth = ikey + ":" + signature;
        System.out.println(Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(auth.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)));
        return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(auth.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    }
}
```

The below code is for creation and deletion of user code

```
package com.ciscoduo.bulkgenerator.service;

import com.ciscoduo.bulkgenerator.model.CiscoDuoCreateUserResponse;
import com.ciscoduo.bulkgenerator.model.CiscoDuoDeleteResponse;
import com.ciscoduo.bulkgenerator.utilies.GenerateSignature;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.http.*;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

import java.net.URL;
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.*;

@Service
public class BulKGeneratorUser {

    @Value("${ciscoduo.host}")
    private String host;
    @Value("${ciscoduo.tenantId}")
    private String tenantId;
    @Value("${ciscoduo.tokenFormt}")
    private String tokenFormt;
    @Value("${ciscoduo.userspath}")
    private String userspath;
    private SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z");

    private String currentTime = dateFormat.format(new Date());

    @Autowired
    private GenerateSignature generateSignature;


    private RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

    public CiscoDuoCreateUserResponse createUser(String username) throws Exception {

        String hostname = String.format(host, tenantId);

        String[] keys = tokenFormt.split(":");

        String ikey = keys[0];
        String skey = keys[1];

        List<String> urlArgs = List.of(currentTime, "POST", hostname, userspath);
        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
        params.put("username", username);


        String url = String.format("https://api-43c07036.duosecurity.com/admin/v1/users?username=%s", username);
        String token = generateSignature.generateTheToken(urlArgs,params, ikey,skey);
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED);
        headers.set("Authorization", "Basic " + token);
        headers.set(HttpHeaders.DATE, currentTime);
        HttpEntity<Object> entity = new HttpEntity<>(headers);
        ResponseEntity<CiscoDuoCreateUserResponse> ciscoDuoResponse = restTemplate.
                exchange(url, HttpMethod.POST, entity, CiscoDuoCreateUserResponse.class);
        return ciscoDuoResponse.getBody();
    }

    public CiscoDuoDeleteResponse deleteUser(String userId) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeyException {
        String hostname = String.format(host, tenantId);
        String[] keys = tokenFormt.split(":");
        String ikey = keys[0];
        String skey = keys[1];
        //String path=String.join("",userspath,"/",userId);
        String path = userspath + "/" + userId;
        System.out.println("path" + path);
        List<String> urlArgs = List.of(currentTime, "DELETE", hostname, path);
        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
        String token = generateSignature.generateTheToken(urlArgs, params, ikey,skey);
        String url = String.format("https://api-43c07036.duosecurity.com/admin/v1/users/%s", userId);
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED);
        headers.set("Authorization", "Basic " + token);
        headers.set(HttpHeaders.DATE, currentTime);
        HttpEntity<Object> entity = new HttpEntity<>(headers);
        ResponseEntity<CiscoDuoDeleteResponse> deleteResponse = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.DELETE, entity, CiscoDuoDeleteResponse.class);
        return deleteResponse.getBody();
    }

}
```

The Pojo class are

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.ToString;

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@ToString
public class CiscoDuoCreateUserResponse {

    private String stat;
    private ResponseData response;

    @Data
    public static class ResponseData {
        private long created;
        private String email;
        private String firstname;
        private String status;
        @JsonProperty("user_id")
        private String userId;
        private String username;
    }
}


package com.ciscoduo.bulkgenerator.model;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.ToString;

@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
@ToString
public class CiscoDuoDeleteResponse {

    private String response;
    private String stat;
}
```

application.properties file

```
ciscoduo.host=api-%s.duosecurity.com
ciscoduo.tenantId=43c07036
ciscoduo.tokenFormt=DIEZT523RM4GZ4ETBJBQ:3z9e75OxFp7TuxzHJDWtctntsp2hu0UlkRgr9VxQ
// ciscoduo.tokenFormt=  integrationKey: secretKey
ciscoduo.userspath=/admin/v1/users
```

The main class was

```
import com.ciscoduo.bulkgenerator.model.CiscoDuoCreateUserResponse;
import com.ciscoduo.bulkgenerator.model.CiscoDuoDeleteResponse;
import com.ciscoduo.bulkgenerator.service.BulKGeneratorUser;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManager;
import javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager;
import java.net.URL;

@SpringBootApplication
public class BulkgeneratorApplication implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    private BulKGeneratorUser bulKGeneratorUser;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(BulkgeneratorApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[]{
                new X509TrustManager() {
                    public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                        return null;
                    }
                    public void checkClientTrusted(
                            java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
                    }
                    public void checkServerTrusted(
                            java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
                    }
                }
        };

        try {
            SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
            sc.init(null, trustAllCerts, new java.security.SecureRandom());
            HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }

        for(int i=0;i<1;i++)
        {
            CiscoDuoCreateUserResponse ciscoDuoResponse=bulKGeneratorUser.createUser("Fabric10");

            String userId=ciscoDuoResponse.getResponse().getUserId();

            System.out.println(ciscoDuoResponse+"userId"+userId);

            CiscoDuoDeleteResponse deleteResponse=bulKGeneratorUser.deleteUser(userId);

            System.out.println(deleteResponse);
        }


    }
}
```

The above code is working fine.

The generation of ASCII string like this

```
Tue, 09 Jan 2024 16:41:07 +0530
POST
api-43c07036.duosecurity.com
/admin/v1/users
username=john
```

The generated signature looks like this

```
RElFWlQ1MjNSTTRHWjRFVEJKQlE6OTY1M2QyMTc2NGNkMjdjMDM2YjBiZmRiMDM3MDMxMjY0NmQ4MzQwNQ==
```